# Hard Time Understanding Goals In Journey Builder Despite Documentation

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, goals

After going through the limited Salesforce Documentation, I am just getting a conflicted understanding regarding Journey Goals and am hoping anyone can help me clear that, or help me recreate a journey that I can test it out in my sandbox environment:

1. When is a goal evaluated? Every 24 hours? End of Wait Period? Real Time? And how does it differ depending on whether it is selected as:

- An exit criteria?
- Not selected as exit criteria?

2. The "%" goal evaluated that shows under wait period:

- Is it defined as --> Number of records that entered that wait period/ number of records that met the goal?
- Will this "%" go down if the number of records in the journey keep increasing faster than goals being met?

Finally, Once a record is evaluated as "goal met" in a wait period will that contact be further evaluated at other wait period (if marked to not exit the journey)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goals are mainly suited to evaluate performance of a journey, beyond engagement in each individual activity (e.g. open and click rates of your email sends). The goal should be easily measurable, and something all your journey activities are contributing towards. This could be:

- Making a purchase
- Renewing a subscription
- Submitting a product review
- Etc.

There is a good explanation of Goals in [this help article.](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_goals.htm&type=5)

Whatever your goal is, it should be represented by an entry in a data extension linked to your contact model in a 1:1 cardinality. This will allow you to check, without any doubt, whether this goal has been reached.

Your goal criteria are indeed evaluated (similarly to exit criteria evaluation) upon your contact exiting a wait step - if you have selected the goal to also be exit criteria. So you will need to ensure the updates to the data extension holding the data for your goal criteria are refreshed with a sufficient frequency to ensure the timely evaluation of it. If your goal is not selected as exit criteria, the contact is evaluated every 24 hours. In real life scenarios, this however makes little difference.

As you are writing yourself, there are two options of goal criteria settings:

- As exit criteria
- Not selected as exit criteria

If you select your goal to also be treated as exit criteria, your contact will exit the journey in case of the goal being reached. This is very useful in cases where your journey has tangible goals, like the ones listed above. Imagine you have a journey with 3 emails, which all are asking your contact to renew a subscription. If this renewal happens after email #1, why bother the contact with emails #2 and #3? In this case, you will reach your goal AND kick your contact out of the journey when the individual exits the wait step separating email #1 and #2.

There might be cases where goal criteria should be tracked while keeping the contact in the journey. In this case, you will select the goal to not also be your exit criteria.

I am not sure about the percentage under the wait step - but I will assume it is how many of the people being in this wait step have been evaluated against the goal criteria. As I wrote above, if you don't have your goal set as exit criteria, your contacts will be evaluated once every 24 hours. Hence the percentage will decrease slightly from the time the contacts enter until their initial evaluation.